# write cordova plugin and overwrite an existing java code

Tags: android, cordova

I am writing `MainActivity.java` in my custom Cordova plugin.

I would like to replace the existing `MainActivity.java` with my custom `MainActivity.java`

But I am getting error

```
Error: Uh oh! "<path>\MainActivity.java" already exists!
```

in `plugin.xml` I have specified

```
<source-file src="src/android/MainActivity.java" target-dir="<path>" />
```

Here `<path>` will be any path, say `src/com/example`

Is there any additional attribute inside `source-file` tag to overwrite?

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite MainActivity.java? I'm sure you can achieve what you want without replacing MainActivity.java. In any case, you won't be able to do it with a source-file tag, but you can probably do it with a hook

Comment: I assume hooks are slightly complex in nature, arranging with numbers etc

Comment: What you want to do is complex, so it requires a complex solution like hooks. Hooks are just node scripts (I think you can use bash scripts too)

Comment: if I write hooks with shell scripts then I need to maintain the line numbers to merge java code in MainActivity.java, which is again another milestone

Answer (score -1):

Change the `source-file` target path like following:

```
source-file src="src/android/MainActivity.java" target-dir="src/com/example/test/
```

Comment: you mean the last **/** slash will fix this issue?

Comment: what path u was given?

Comment: let us assume the same path you have given

Comment: otherwise remove previous plugin and then install current one